# How to display an image from url into Qlabel

Tags: image, url, qlabel, pytube, pafy

I made an app to download YouTube videos using **pafy**, and it works fine.
Here is a code snippet:

```
    # Display video's thumbnail
    thumbnail = Image.open(requests.get(self.video.thumb, stream=True).raw)
    video_thumbnail = QImage(ImageQt(thumbnail))
    self.lblThumbnail.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(video_thumbnail))
```

But, when I used **pytube**, it didn't work.
Here is a code snippet:

```
    # Display video's thumbnail
    thumbnail = Image.open(requests.get(self.video.thumbnail_url, stream=True).raw)
    video_thumbnail = QImage(ImageQt(thumbnail))
    self.lblThumbnail.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(video_thumbnail))
```

Nothing different except **thumbnail_url**, both thumbnail_url and thumb are strings.

The apps freezes, then crashes without displaying any error in the terminal.
Any suggestions are welcomed

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution, sorry for inconvenience I didn't search YouTube
Here is a great simple solution

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynW_vIPVNbc

Thanks